# Is there a way to get current number of tokens parsed in stack in yacc

Tags: yacc, lex

I am running into parser stack overflow in yacc. I am not sure how is the current parser stack size determined. IS there a way to get current parser stack size, so that once the number of tokens reaches the maximum stack depth, an error can be reported? Is there a variable in yacc that holds this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to get the parser stack size, although obviously it is internally available since the parser is capable of producing a stack overflow error (without segfaulting or otherwise invoking undefined behaviour). You don't need to check this yourself; you simply need to print the error message provided to `yyerror`; if the stack overflows, the error message will mention that fact.

There are a few ways you can end up with a version of yàcc which doesn't resize the stack. One is the use of the public domain Berkeley yacc, often called `byacc`; the version I have kicking around (from 1993) sets the default stack size to 500.

Another possibility is to use Gnu `bison`, compiling the result with a C++ compiler; by default, this will make the stack non-relocatable since `bison` doesn't know whether the semantic value union is trivially copyable. (Newer versions of bison might not have this restriction.) By default, the initial bison stack size is 200.

A common way to blow up stacks is to use right recursion for long lists. A particularly bad one is some variant on the following:

```
program: /* empty */
       | statement program
       ;
```

which will cause the parser stack overflow if a "program" is too long. It's usually sufficient to just change that to left recursion:

```
program: /* empty */
       | program statement
       ;
```